# Check if a String follows a certain format?

Tags: java, string

I have written a program that takes a ASCII character input (it actually takes a String then I use charAt(0)) into a JTextField then displays its hex, binary, int, and octal values using g2d.drawString(). I want the ability to also put in "integer" values (again actually being Strings) and display the info. In order to separate the "integer" values from the "char" inputs, I want to be able to input char values as they are, and integers using the pattern `#i`. This way, I can use an if statement to check if the "integer" pattern is followed, otherwise (else) evaluate the input as a ascii "char". How can I check if a String follows this pattern?

**Example:**

*char input:*

`3 //I'll evaluate this as the ascii character value of 3`

*int input:*

`3i //I'll evaluate this as the integer value of 3`

Note: Integer inputs could be multiple digits.

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm if this is what you are talking about, seems like it could be the thing. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, the question I'm asking is, do you know what a regular expression is and have you tried it, but as it seems the answer would be (generally) no, but know you do, so all is awesome! ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yup nailed it. Thank you very much, glad you and Logan showed me this, seems like a very usefull concept. I didn't realize there was a whole class built to find String patterns. When I look for patterns, I normally split the String into a char array and loop through the array looking for characters I need using switch statements. Of course, in this case that didn't work since I didn't know the length of the String since the value entered could be many digits.

Comment: Oh yes, you should *definitely* learn about regular expressions. They can be very powerful when used right, but they can't do everything, e.g. they can't process complex nested syntax, even though a lot of people keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if (str.length() == 1) {
    char ch = charAt(0);
    // code here
} else if (str.endsWith("i")) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
    // code here
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input: " + str);
}
```

The `parseInt()` will throw `NumberFormatException` if value preceding the `i` is not valid. Since that is a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`, the code above will throw `IllegalArgumentException` for *any* bad text.

Comment: Now interestingly enough, in this case specifically this will work since I know that the 'i' will always be at the end. However, in a general sense, Logan/MadProgrammer's way was better because it allowed more adaptability. @MadProgrammer which one should I accept? The one that is better in general, or the more specific case that better answers this question specifically.

Comment: @AshwinGupta You should accept the one that is most acceptable to *you*, but you can up-vote all answers that you find *useful*.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Even though regex can do this, and is good at it, it's really overkill for your particular purpose. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the advice! Also I will definitely try to learn regex. For now, I have the program working. I actually figured out another way, I can use a swing JList to select if its an int or char.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class. You will be able to do what you want with this.

Comment: Thank you Logan. As usual. Javadoc has the answer!

Comment: You are welcome, haha. This has come in handy for me before.

Comment: Logan, I accepted Andreas' answer because it made more sense in context, however, yours was great too and I upvoted.

Comment: No problem. Thank you.